# Invalid configFile (Cypress 10.0) - cannot find module

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm trying to convert my Cypress configFile to use with Cypress 10.0+

I've followed the new documentation, however Cypress is stating my file is invalid.

"Error: Cannot find module 'cypress'"

Here's the config I'm trying to use...

```
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
    e2e: {
        specPattern: "tests/e2e/**/*.cy.js",
        supportFile: "tests/support/e2e.js"
    },
    projectId: "zpk6q6",
    reporter: "junit",
    reporterOptions: {
        mochaFile: "tests/test-output-[hash].xml",
        toConsole: true,
        attachments: true
    }
})
```

Hopefully someone else in the Cypress community can assist me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you use a direct download to get Cypress? If so, try replacing `module.exports = defineConfig({` with `module.exports = {` and remove the `require` (Info here: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/21999)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve this.

Before I run `npx cypress run...`, I needed to actually install Cypress. So my command looks like

```
npm install cypress --save-dev
npx cypress run --browser chrome
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
npm install cypress --save-dev --force
```